# Filling a listbox from a textbox without using a button or click event in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm not sure if it is possible, but I would like to know if a listbox can be updated by adding or removing text by typing that text into a textbox without using a button event or some type of click event.  I've tried using the text_changed event but it inserts the text as I type so I am unable to type an entire string and then move that into a listbox as a whole string.

What I am trying to do is scan a magnetic ID card through a reader and have it insert the data from that card into a listbox and when I scan the same card again, it will remove the data.  This is for an employee logging system.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to decide how you know that the user has finished typing in the TextBox (e.g. when the user hits Enter, or when the user hits Tab), then handle that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code, if you type a string in `TextBox1` and hit Enter, we check to see if the string already exists in `ListBox1`. If so, the string is removed from the ListBox, otherwise it is added. Then `TextBox1` is cleared.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = vbCr Then
        If ListBox1.Items.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(TextBox1.Text)
        Else
            ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        End If
        TextBox1.Clear()
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are awesome.  Thanks so much for the help.  This will definitely get me in the right direction for the rest of the program.